# iOS get video frame rate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, video, frame-rate

I want to get the frame rate for a specific video. I tried to look at APIs in the `AVFoundation` and `AssetsLibrary` like AVURLAsset or AVAssetReader. None of them are really helpful. Does anybody know a method in the Apple's frameworks/library to get the frame rate

Comment: It seems like the correct answer is now @AddisDev's answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For iOS 7+ you can use the currentVideoFrameRate property of AVPlayerItemTrack. Its the only consistent property that I've seen measure FPS. The nominalFrameRate property seems to be broken in HLS streams.

```
AVPlayerItem *item = AVPlayer.currentItem; // Your current item
float fps = 0.00;
for (AVPlayerItemTrack *track in item.tracks) {
    if ([track.assetTrack.mediaType isEqualToString:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
        fps = track.currentVideoFrameRate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The easier option is to obtain an AVAssetTrack and read its nominalFrameRate property.
Looks like [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetTrack_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAssetTrack/hasMediaCharacteristic:) can help you.

**Nominal frame rate is the frame rate of the track, in frames per second.** (read-only)
AVAssetTrack Class
@property(nonatomic, readonly) float nominalFrameRate

Comment: If @AddisDev is correct, this no longer should be considered the right answer. Can someone verify?

Answer (score 2):

For the property `currentVideoFrameRate`, from Apple's [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritemtrack/1388956-currentvideoframerate):

> If the item is not playing, or if the media type of the track is not
>   video, the value of this property is 0.0.

It requires the item is in "playing", so I used `nominalFrameRate` instead.

It still works in iOS 12, swift 4:

```
let tracks = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)

let fps = tracks?.first?.nominalFrameRate
```

Remember to handle nil checking.